# What is the best way to parse a line using Java?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to write a small Java application, and part of its job is to read, write, and parse lines from text files. My problem though is taking a line from a text file, reading it, and breaking it into parts. For example, an example line is:

`Tuesday, 11/11/14 10:30:32: 3.93`

I want my program to be able to look at this and fill up for example a `string day = "tuesday"`, and `value = 3.93`.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(itemValue);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
    int[] value;

}
fileReader.close();
System.out.println("Contents of file:");
System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

This is the code I currently have - it will parse through my file and print out line by line into the console, but I don't really know how to actually process the line. I've tried using bufferedReader.readLine as the variable containing the line, but that doesn't seem to be the answer. I'm extremely new to Java and this is a big roadblock in my programming, so if anybody could point me toward a solution, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: All of my data looks exactly the same, here is the rest of it.

```
Tuesday, 11/11/14 10:29:23: 4.48
Tuesday, 11/11/14 10:29:27: 5.0
Tuesday, 11/11/14 10:29:39: 5.95
Tuesday, 11/11/14 10:29:46: 6.0
Tuesday, 11/11/14 18:07:25: 4.0
Tuesday, 11/11/14 18:07:27: 4.5
Tuesday, 11/11/14 18:07:33: 5.0
Tuesday, 11/11/14 18:07:39: 5.9
Tuesday, 11/11/14 18:07:51: 20.0
```

Comment: There are a large number of possible answers, depending on what your test data looks like and how consistent it is. Please show us a small example of your test data (more than one line).

Comment: I've added some more of my data - it is all exactly the same format. Speaking of formatting, I'm new to this website as well and apparently I broke something - they are not all on the same line, each day/date/time/double should be on its own line.

Comment: That's ok - I've fixed it.

Comment: It's still very unclear what it is you are trying to accomplish. Please provide examples of your desired output for the provided input. Also, why is value initialized, then never used. I'm assuming that this is just where you left off before you hit this roadblock, but some more context around what you want to do there would help us to provide assistance.

Comment: Use `line.split("\\s+")`. Here `\\s+` is a pattern for "1 or more whitespace character"

Comment: Value is unused, I was trying to use an array and haven't deleted it yet. What I'm trying to do is parse through all of the lines in my data as I have posted above, and fill an array with all of the doubles, and eventually find the average of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the most popular approaches to parsing this kind of data are `String.split()`, and using a regular expression.

With `String.split()` you might do something like this:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
    // now each part of the input line (separated by whitespace) is in a different element of the parts array
}
```

If you choose to use a regular expression, and you wanted the first and last parts, you might try a regular expression like:

```
^(A-Za-z), .*? (0-9\.)$
```

Of course there will be other code required to execute it. Do a google search for "regular expressions".

Answer (score 2):

You could try to break up each line by white space using a delimiter.

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String values[] = line.split("\\s+");

}
```

This gives you some starting point to work with each bit of data in the line. As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481248/jason) pointed out in the comments, it can vary widely, depending on the implementation.

In this case, for example, you could parse the last item in each `values[]` to a double. It's up to you.